# Unable to override actioinBarWidgetTheme for Theme.AppCompat.Light, using AppCompat v21

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I try to style my v7.widget.Toolbar's menu radio buttons to use a custom drawable.

This **works**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

But I guess this will change all of my apps radio buttons while I'd like to limit it to Toolbar only, so I am extracting to a custom theme and arrive to this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyAbTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAbTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Now, the above **doesn't work** - I have material-ish radio buttons which are default.
I also tried to do this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyAbTheme"
    />
(+ in styles.xml change parent to overlay like this)

<style name="MyAbTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

but this doesn't do anything too.

Any hints of how I would style only radio buttons in a Toolbar?

Comment: to limit style to Toolbar only apply it to toolbar in xml resource

Answer (score 0):

Regards the second attempt:

- AppCompat does not have the `Theme.AppCompat.Dark`, or am I wrong?
- can be related to property's value *null* `<item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@null</item>` in **values/theme_base.xml** of AppCompat, but i cannot explain because. Maybe this property is not longer used.
- have you tried with and without `android:` prefix?

Comment: 1. That's "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark", 2. dunno 3. No, it makes no sense, "android:" prefix needs to be omitted only for 5+ sdk attributes iirc